# Getting two variables from one radio button?

Tags: php, mysql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy3o0.png

That is what the site looks like now. What I want to do is when you click on the approve registration on the table, it will extract the value of the id no and the name of that particular record. I thought i was on the right track. I knew how to get the id no. But it doesn't get the value of the name at the same time.

This is how the code looks like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mayor))
{
    $id = $row['identification_no'];
    $name = $row['lastname'].", ".$row['firstname'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><form method=post action=approvedmayor.php><input type='radio' name=id value='$id'></td>";
}
```

approvedmayor.php

```
$query = mysql_query("insert into tbcandidates VALUES ($id, '$name', 'mayor')"); 

if ($query)
{
    echo "You appproved ";
    echo $name;
}

else
    echo "error";
```

Comment: Use checkboxes to retrieve multiple values. Radio gives only one value at a time.. it build for that stuff only.

Comment: There are multiple values inside the radio button for the table. Did you look at the screenshot? I was meant to get the value of two fields from the table using one button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this...

```
<?php

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mayor))
{
$id = $row['identification_no'];
$name = $row['lastname'].", ".$row['firstname'];

echo "<tr><td><a href='approvedmayor.php?id=$id&name=$name'>Approve</a></td></tr>";
}

?>
```

in this type don't use the form, and Approve button... try this alone

Comment: How would you get the value of $name? POST method doesn't work. The Id is the only one passed.

Comment: @user1551672 you can get this using GET method

Comment: @user1551672 did you tried like this, $id=$_GET['id']; $name=$_GET['name'];

Comment: I tried what you edited. How can you submit the selected radio button if there is no form? You cant just click on the radio button in my case.

Comment: @user1551672 am not used radio button, see i used only link with a name approve, if you click that , it will redirect...

Comment: it does not redirect to anything when you provided an a href tag on a radio button.

Comment: @user1551672 am not used radio button, see my updated code.. am used this code '<a href='approvedmayor.php?id=$id&name=$name'>Approve</a>' with in <td> tag

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is bad practice to insert that kind of data directly from `POST` data.
If you have all these candidates already stored in the database, you should run a `SELECT` query in your `approvedmayor.php` first, and if the candidate still exists, insert it's data to another table.

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `candidates` WHERE `id` = '.$id.' LIMIT 1');
if(mysql_num_rows($query)) {

  $candidate = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

  $insertQuery = mysql_query("insert into tbcandidates VALUES ($candidate['id'], $candidate['name'], $candidate['mayor'])"); 

  if ($insertQuery) {
    echo "You appproved ";
    echo $name;
  } else echo "error";

} else echo 'This candidate is no longer available';
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question,

But thats not the best way go ahead, Before we move let us understand some little elements functions

`Radio Button` : Its an input type element, that allows the user to choose only `one` [ 1 ] of option given list.

`Check Boxes` : Its an input type element, that allows the user to select `n` number of options or selections from give list.

Fore info - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Now comming to your question..

You need to modify your code to `check boxes` as below

```
<input type='checkbox' name=id[] value='$id'>
```

Notice : elements name is in Array mode.. ie whenever a user one or more than one, the values are stored in array.

Once the values are stored in array, call it / use if however you want.

### For your mentioned code

```
echo "<form method=post action=approvedmayor.php>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mayor))
{
    $id = $row['identification_no'];
    $name = $row['lastname'].", ".$row['firstname'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='radio' name=id[] value='$id'></td>";
}
echo "</form>";
```

### approvedmayor.php

```
$temp_app_arr = $_POST['id'];

foreach ($temp_app_arr as $pos => $val) {
    $query = mysql_query("insert into tbcandidates VALUES ('$val', '$name', 'mayor')"); 

    if ($query) {
        echo "You appproved ";
        echo $name;
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

}
```

And i believe this should gonna be good code / algorithm for your project.

Comment: Where would you get the value of $name from the first file? The only thing it would get is the id.

Comment: What! its your `sql query`, you know better yours database and tables